# move div from it's parents using just CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Thinking about responsive design I wolud like to know, is it posible to "adopt" some divs in certain screen widths? I know you can reorder them but is there any way to move divs from a container to another?
For example: Let's say a have an  with a search input on it (and other stuff), could I move it into the  section and move the remainder  to the bottom of the page in smaller screens?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just separate them from the beginning and then reorder as needed?

Comment: Yes, the real intention is to use it in a wordpress template and I need to define the header, content, footer, widget area, etc... in order to avoid other problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in JavaScript you can put an element into another with something like this:

```
var myDiv=document.getElementById("myDivId");
var destinationDiv=document.getElementById("destinationDivId");
destinationDiv.appendChild(myDiv);
```

or if you mean moving a div graphically with css

you can use css positioning (position:absolute or relative, and top,left params)

and maybe  "transition".....

Comment: I thought about the positioning but some mobile devices make a really mess when you try it no matter if you use px, em or even %. Also I was trying to avoid the javascript for the mobile version but also think its probably the best option...